# No progress bar when copying files with newer versions of Nautilus (Ubuntu 17.10 and later)

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, copy

When copying or moving files on Ubuntu 17.10, I can't see any progress bar. I checked as well all opened windows but I can't see any progress window.

Please any ideas or suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: So , if I've got this correct. The developers of Nautilus don't like the idea of someone choosing to copy files to their own desktop, so, no progress indicator for desktopers ? I'd suggest installing another file manager. Sorted!

Comment: One option, if you're using Unity, is to install Nemo: https://askubuntu.com/a/1042321/138621

Answer (score 30):

In recent versions of Files (aka Nautilus) separate copy/move status window is no longer available. Instead, you should see a circular symbol (animated pie-chart to show progress) at the top-right of Files window.

Click on it to see details.

[image]

Comment: That is not the case always. When you are copying something to the desktop you can not see anything

Comment: I mean when you are inside a folder then you can see the icon but in the desktop where should it appear !!! of course it will not appear I feel this not a bug but the person behind that is very stupid.

Comment: @Navaro To be honest GNOME developers don't like the idea of putting files in desktop. In fact they have removed the desktop icon feature altogether from the latest version (3.28) of Nautilus!

Comment: @Navaro But thankfully (?) Ubuntu developers have decided to ship Ubuntu 18.04 with Nautilus v3.26 instead of 3.28 just to provide the desktop icons feature for users.

Comment: That's really great because I was thinking to switch back to windows 10 with bash instead of Ubuntu as an OS.