# How to install the (latest version of) Nemo in Ubuntu 18.04 without cinnamon dependencies?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, 18.04, filemanager, nemo

In previous Ubuntu versions there was a **[Nemo version without cinnamon dependencies](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/11/nemo-320-with-unity-patches-and-without.html)** but [the PPA does not](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3) (yet?) include a version for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.
 Is there another way to **install the (latest version of) Nemo in Ubuntu 18.04 without cinnamon dependencies**?

Comment: I use it here in 18.04 but with unity as most of that ppa's patches are for unity integration. Are you looking to just to remobe the cinnamon deps but use in a gnome session? (gnome-session

Comment: @doug Yes, correct. I would like to use Nemo in a Gnome session (Ubuntu default) without the cinnamon dependencies.

Comment: Well long story short I had ppa'd the webupd8 version for bionic during dev in anticipation of libgnome-desktop-3 upgrading but didn't notice nemo was going to also upgrade. So the ppa became useless for many unless they knew how to install downgrades (both ppa & repo were same version.) There was no simple way to rebuild in a ppa & I'm not inclined to fix the patches for the new libgnome-desktop-3 version. Note also that this was done specifically for a unity session so removed 2 patches & put in a more useful .desktop for unity' s launcher icon's actions though could also work ok in gnome.

Comment: So to help out some users I recently came up with a way to rebuild to reversion higher. The ppa is here, if inclined to use i'd purge nemo if already installed & autoremove any other nemo packages (4 in total). Then install nemo & see.. https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/bionic-noprop

Comment: @doug Thank you very much, Doug! Hopefully you don't mind that I turned it into an answer!

Comment: Not at all. Just to note: the reason for the ppa was for 18.04 unity users who've tired of nautilus.. To that end I did remove the orig. ppa's dbus  & .desktop patches & put in my own .desktop file patch so there were constant xdg folder quickists.  Also note that if anyone who uses the ppa tries to get it's nemo build-dep they will fail as to get a new build required a sleigh of hand regarding libgnome-desktop-3-dev & the one used for the ppa is not in the ppa (for good reason, the libgnome-desktop-3 build in the ppa only has the shared lib..

Comment: @doug Thanks again! I don't really understand everything ;-). What do you mean with "the one used for the ppa is not in the ppa"? Your PPA - WebUpd8-PPA?
Are there any caveats the normal user (Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome desktop)? Will you be able to add an update of Nemo in the future?

Comment: While both libgnome-desktop-3-12 & 3-17 can co-exist in an install (or ppa) there can only be 1 libgnome-desktop-3-dev package  (-dev packages are rarely 'versioned'). So any ppa (or local) build using that -dev package would use the current source version (3-17) in 18.04 which would fail without reworking the patches. To work around that I created a 'mirror' build of the 3-12 source in another ppa & versioned it so the build system would use that to build nemo. If users happened to install that -dev & gir1 packages it could cause issue so it's been hidden away so to speak.

Comment: If you were to take a look at the package details in the ppa you'd see the libgnome-desktop-3 build there only has the -data and shared lib packages, no -dev & gir1 packages.

Comment: @doug Thank you for this helpful answer, even I could understand it ;-).

Comment: @doug Thank you for this. Even compiling some extensions from here: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions
however, I seem to be now affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1170647 - which was fixed in 16.04 for Nautilus. Any idea why it reappears when using Nemo as default file manager? I thought they just fixed BAMF for this.

Comment: @sup - maybe because I did not enable the `12_unity_launcher_support.patch` when building nemo. Using that patch creates the poor behavior regarding the default xdg folders from the laucher quicklists that's also seen in nautilus. So I've no intention of enabling that patch as that behavior is more important to me than a minimized external volume behavior (if in fact that patch would solve...

Comment: Nah, the repo nemo shows same behavior regarding minimized external volumes. If you can locate what fixed it & it's not nautilus specific I'd take a look..though I believe it is nautilus specific.

Comment: @doug I think it is this branch that fixed it: https://code.launchpad.net/~3v1n0/unity/launcher-filemanager-integration Nautilus is mentioned in the diff files only with regards to launchers. I tried replacing "nautilus" with "nemo" in all the desktop files that have nautilus in their name but that did not help.

As for quicklist and default XDG folders, I use custom folders and Nemo fails with those (unless my changing the desktopfiles caused that.

Comment: @doug Have you tried looking into it?

Comment: yeah, it was done for nautilus not nemo. Nothing to be done there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Doug](https://askubuntu.com/users/27773/doug) provided a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/bionic-noprop) for **install** the **Nemo** in **Ubuntu 18.04 (only)** **without cinnamon dependencies** (see his [comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/1695501?noredirect=1)).
*F**or newer Ubuntu versions**: A unity session using Nemo in 20.04 can be set up to work reasonably well, especially if you use a modified nemo.desktop in the launcher* (see [Doug's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032252/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-nemo-in-ubuntu-18-04-without-cinnamon-dep/1042321?noredirect=1#comment2184855_1042321)).

He recommends to **purge** the installed nemo files before installing the new version. I did the following:

```
sudo apt purge cinnamon-desktop-data cinnamon-l10n gist hddtemp hwdata inxi libcinnamon-desktop4 libnemo-extension1 libxapp1 mesa-utils nemo nemo-data nemo-fileroller ruby-json xapps-common
```

Then added the **PPA**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/bionic-noprop
sudo apt-get update
```

Then **install Nemo**:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

To make Nemo the **default file manager**:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

To **handle the desktop** just disable nautilus:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Reboot or log out

**Thank you, [Doug](https://askubuntu.com/users/27773/doug), for this great option.**

Comment: As that was orig. just a ppa to insure I had working patched nemo for myself just decided today to  change to "Label" (displayed name, not actual ppa name). If any issue with package manager or apt left simple instructions at bottom of description on main ppa page.  Should only take a min. to do one time 'fix'  https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/bionic-noprop Also added a mediainfo-tab plugin & fixed the media-columns plugin.

Comment: Comment from [user x7i7l](https://askubuntu.com/users/894108/x7i7l): For some reason, on KDE Neon, Doug's repository doesn't help me. I've followed all the instructions but no matter what I do it still pulls in Cinnamon dependencies. I checked and Muon package manager is pulling in Doug's version.
@doug Do you have an answer?

Comment: run `apt-show nemo` check the deps & recommends, see if any of those are causing this in muon

Comment: @x7i7l You probably figured it out, it is `apt show nemo` (not apt-show).

Comment: @doug Is there a possibility to update Nemo in your PPA to a newer version? I think [version 4.0.6](https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo) is already out. Cheers!

Comment: @ Filbuntu, no, that would require redoing most of the patches and switching to a meson build. Not worth it..

Comment: @doug Thank you for the response. It is a pity it is a lot of work. Nemo often crashes, especially when viewing folders with pictures in the icon view.

Comment: @doug Can the PPA be used for Ubuntu 20.04 too?

Comment: No,  those patches will only work in 18.04. That being said a unity session using nemo in 20.04 can be set up to work reasonably well, especially if you use a modified nemo.desktop in the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the only (temporary) solution is to use the artful packages which should work (they're working for me) since Ubuntu 17.10 uses Gnome Shell anyway.

Just change `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-nemo3-bionic.list` to read `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/nemo3/ubuntu artful main`
You can also use the GUI by opening "Software & Updates" and editing the repo there, by changing `bionic` to `artful`.

Eventually, a Bionic repo will be available and then we can change the source again.

Comment: I don't experience any of those problems, it's as stable as it's always been. Make sure you don't have all configurations stored from previous Ubuntu versions

Comment: Unfortunately Nemo crashes now & then (twice a day), especially when looking at the icons in a folder with mainly pictures.

Comment: See my runaway comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Moilleadóir you are right. Sudo apt install nemo would install the standard repo version (along with Cinnamon desktop).

To install nemo=3.6.5-1~webupd8~artful01 you need libgnome-desktop-3.so.12.
In Bionic default is libgnome-desktop-3.so.17.
Without this package (libgnome-desktop-3.so.12) nemo (3.6.5-1~webupd8~artful01) won’t start.

I found workaround (but you do it on your own risks):

First off all you need to add nemo artful packages (Felipe presnts how to do it)

Secend step: you need to manual install libgnome-desktop-3.so.12

You can found it here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/libgnome-desktop-3-12/download

```
sudo dpkg -i libgnome-desktop-3-12_3.26.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Next step:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-data=3.6.5-1~webupd8~artful0

sudo apt-get install nemo=3.6.5-1~webupd8~artful01 

sudo apt-get install nemo-fileroller=3.6.0-1~webupd8~artful
```

To avoid actualization to sdandard repo version:

```
echo "nemo hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

echo "nemo-data hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

echo "nemo-fileroller hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: Thank you for this workaround! I really hope there will be an easier way or the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/nemo3) will be updated, though, as this workaround sounds a bit risky for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since 16.04, I've more or less followed Filibuntu's answer, just with different PPAs along the way. (I never bother replacing the desktop though. Just add the PPA, install, and go.) Even in 18.04 I never ran into the problem of the stock repo version being newer than the PPA.

That's all different now with Focal and it took me forever to figure it out. Some of these suggestions seemed promising but ultimately didn't work. This is what I got working:

```
## Install Python 3.7 from PPA https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=focal
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get install python3.7

## Add recent Nemo PPA from ## https://launchpad.net/~darovic/+archive/ubuntu/nemo?field.series_filter=disco
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:darovic/nemo

## Change distro version name from e.g. "focal" to "disco"
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/darovic-ubuntu-nemo-focal.list
sudo apt-get update

## Install specific PPA version
sudo apt-get install nemo=4.2.2-darovic0  libnemo-extension1=4.2.2-darovic0  nemo-data=4.2.2-darovic0  python-nemo=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-audio-tab=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-compare=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-emblems=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-filename-repairer=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-fileroller=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-gtkhash=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-image-converter=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-media-columns=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-pastebin=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-preview=4.2.0-darovic0  python-nemo=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-seahorse=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-share=4.2.0-darovic0  nemo-terminal=4.2.0-darovic0  xreader=2.2.3-darovic0
```

This should be adaptable to future versions of *buntu and Darovic's Nemo build, within reason.

Answer (score -1):

[This was a comment but it was too long!]

I have doubts about this working as it used to. The versions of Nemo in the webupd8team repo and the standard Universe repo are the same, but the Universe repo (version `3.6.5-1`) is marked ‘bionic’ whereas the webupd8team one (version `3.6.5-1~webupd8~artful01`) is marked ‘artful’. My guess is that `sudo apt install nemo` would install the standard repo version (<strike>along with Cinnamon desktop</strike>).

You could use **Package | Force Version…** in Synaptic to force the webupd8team version. I’m not sure if `sudo apt install nemo=3.6.5-1~webupd8~artful01` would work or not as `apt-cache policy nemo` doesn’t list it as a candidate (i.e. it’s the wrong release).

If you run `apt-cache policy nemo` what version does it show is installed?

---

**EDIT:** I decided to gradually create a new 18.04 install in a VM, rather than upgrading 16.04 in August, so I’ve just got back to looking at this. The Nemo version in the standard repos **does not** install the Cinnamon desktop (unlike Caja which does look like it installs Mate). In my (limited) testing so far it seems to run fine.

Comment: You are right, it was the Universe repo version "3.6.5-1" that was installed with this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033389/30631) and not the 3.6.5-1~webupd8~artful01 and the Cinnamon desktop was installed as well.