# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Nemo

Tags: 18.04, nemo

I would like to install `Nemo` file manager in `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, however I read that installing from Ubuntu software or via `apt` would also install cinnamon dependencies, and this could be risky for the system integrity. Is that true? 
 [An article](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/how-to-replace-nautilus-with-nemo-file.html) at linuxuprising speaks of "some annoyances/inconveniences", such as the sidebar has a gray area at the bottom and the file/folder rename box doesn't have a border: if these are the only issues, they are certainly tolerable.
I also read a 10 months old [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032252/467407) at askubuntu, where I discovered that there is a `ppa` with a `Nemo` version without cinnamon dependencies, but still after 10 months it does not include a version for Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. 
 
What would you suggest to do? Using [Nemo for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/bionic-noprop) by Doug McMahon is a valid and safe solution?

Comment: I use nemo from `universe` and it works just perfect.

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/nemo. Besides a single small cinnamon library, no dependencies for the cinnamon desktop.

Comment: nemo from `universe` is the official package which can be found and installed from Ubuntu software?

Comment: [Universe - Community-maintained free and open-source software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

Comment: You would be better using the repo Nemo, it works ok and is a newer version of the one in ppa (which is for 18.04 and only 18.04 so don't understand your statement there..) The ppa version is meant for a unity session & also meant to handle the desktop & be default file manager. The only downside of that nemo version is it's slow to search files, this was fixed in the newer version.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see any problems here:

1. Add the *universe* repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   ```
2. Install Nemo ([`nemo` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=nemo))

   - with default dependencies

     ```
     sudo apt-get install nemo
     ```

     > The following NEW packages will be installed:
     >   cinnamon-desktop-data cinnamon-l10n fonts-lato gawk gist hddtemp hwdata inxi
     >   javascript-common libcinnamon-desktop4 libjs-jquery libnemo-extension1
     >   libpython-stdlib libruby2.5 libsigsegv2 libxapp1 lm-sensors mesa-utils nemo
     >   nemo-data nemo-fileroller net-tools python python-minimal python2.7
     >   python2.7-minimal rake ruby ruby-did-you-mean ruby-json ruby-minitest
     >   ruby-net-telnet ruby-power-assert ruby-test-unit ruby2.5
     >   rubygems-integration xapps-common
   - or without recommended dependencies

     ```
     sudo apt-get install nemo --no-install-recommends
     ```

     > The following NEW packages will be installed:
     >   cinnamon-desktop-data libcinnamon-desktop4 libnemo-extension1
     >   libpython-stdlib libxapp1 nemo nemo-data python python-minimal python2.7
     >   python2.7-minimal xapps-common

   The latter seems to be the solution for your question.