# Stuck for applying permissions with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: permissions, mount, external-hdd, chmod, chown

This worked on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine.  I just switched to Ubuntu 18.04.  This isn't working.

It's all updated.

I plugged in an external drive.  I went and looked at the drive through the gui, if that matters.  It does matter on an Ubuntu live CD vm apparently.  So I did that.

On the 14 machine, I had to do this initially with an external drive so I had permissions on it.  Maybe I also went through the gui properties permissions to set that to read/write.  It's been a while.

chown -R myUbuntu18account: /media/myubuntu18account/longdrivenumber

I thought that solved it in the past, at least on Ubuntu 14.

I tried copying -- both through the gui and from terminal -- but when I copy folders/files off the external drive, I only get some of them.  The external drive folder might be 20GB.  I get 500MB worth of files.  I checked permisisons on the files in the folder and it looks like most don't have my account listed with read/write permissions.

Am I missing or forgetting something?  I'm pretty sure on Ubuntu 14 I just plugged the drive in, got the long, unique number off the drive's properties, and did a "chown -R account: /media/account/longnumber" and I was good to go for working with the external drive, meaning that I could just copy to and from it with ctrl-c and ctrl-v.

Help!!!   Maybe it's something with setting permissions specifically, chmod xyz stuff, but I don't remember having to do that.  I'm looking at notes and don't see anything like that before.  Plus, I popped drive in and out often enough I'd remember.

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `ls -l /media/$USER` with the external drive attached and mounted into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: What is the filesystem on your external drive?

Comment: I would have formatted the external drive as gpt and ext4.

Comment: ls -l /media/$USER gives me....  (Fine, a new post since I can't hit Enter here...)

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 1 accountname accountname 4096 Jun 6 16:01 longnumberforexternaldrive

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 9 accountname accountname 4096 Jul 26 10:17 longnumberfor2ndexternaldrive

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's this.
[No progress bar when copying files on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019330/no-progress-bar-when-copying-files-on-ubuntu-17-10)
There's a circle instead of a progress bar now.  If I click on that, I do get the progress bar.

While copying, I got a permissions box pop up.  Last week the copying eventually errored out.  Today it appears to be moving.  No other changes made to permissions.  I did restart the machine, but I tried that last week too.