# Getting an error copying from external drive to desktop

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive

Continued from here.
[Stuck for applying permissions with Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059741/stuck-for-applying-permissions-with-ubuntu-18-04#1060911)

I can copy fine into a folder on the desktop, but not just copying a folder from the external drive over to my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop itself.  I get this error,
"Error while copy.
There was an error getting information about "folder on the external drive".
Show more details
The specified location is not mounted

The external drive looks mounted.  It's visible.  I can copy folders/files from it fine into a folder ON the desktop.  Why can't I just copy to the desktop itself right away though?

Comment: having the exact same issue!

Comment: I am also having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

If your external Drive is FAT12/16, FAT32 or exFAt filesystem, Special Characters  like ?<>\:*|\" are not valid in the file name; you will need to rename them:

From the command line you can use command-line tools such as "rename" to replace these characters with _ or even to remove them:

```
rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]/_/g'    # Change invalid characters to _
rename 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]//g'     # Remove invalid characters
```